# capybara / Observe html5/history route change

Tags: tdd, capybara, bdd, browser-history

as it is somehow possible to wait for ajax calls ([here](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/automatically-wait-for-ajax-with-capybara) and [there](https://coderwall.com/p/aklybw/wait-for-ajax-with-capybara-2-0)), would there be a way to wait for or observe a route change in capybara (html5/browser history) ? Does a route change fire an event that we can listen to ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pushing to or popping from the history should change the current URL so you can use The have_current_path matcher

```
expect(page).to have_current_path("/whatever")
```

Comment: Yep I've checked that; I might not have been accurate enough. Let's say the route changes after an ajax call's response; Id need to wait for both the ajax call and the route change. Isn't there a javascript event to listen to the route change ? I'll edit my question

Comment: @Ben Why do you need to wait for both the ajax and the route change - all you have to wait for is the route change since that would imply the ajax finished too (there really are VERY few cases where wait_for_ajax should ever be needed), which have_current_path will do (up to Capybara.default_max_wait_time seconds, pass a :wait option to have_current_path if you want it to potentially wait longer)

Comment: allright… I might have misunderstood the fact that it *waits* by default if you use the correct methods ( using `expect(current_path).to eq("/somepath")` was obviously a  misleading mistake )

Comment: @Ben All the Capybara provided matchers provide waiting/retrying behavior and should be preferred over the default RSpec provided matchers whenever possible -  `expect(element).to have_text(...)` over `expect(element.text).to eq ...`, etc.

Comment: I get that very well now, sounds like a fundamental concept that i just misunderstood. Thanks alot for pointing this out!